# How to make a Google Maps API (.js) file a part of a widget for Mobiles

Tags: javascript, mobile, maps

I would like to create a Web App for device. For that I would have some script being stored on device, instead of downloading them all time when I start application. As far as I saw including a GoogleMaps API makes some additional request for javascript files. Is there any way of having all of them taken directly from local store? Or is this always have to refeer to google web address? Thanks for any answers here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you always must load them from the Google site. They offer no way to run Google Maps locally. The GMaps scripts are generated on the fly, based upon (among others, I'm sure) the HTTP_REFERER header of the request.  That's how they can bind an API key to a specific website.

Comment: That was probable answer for this question, but I want to be sure uhhh... It just sux a bit but ok..